# the emits options in child component in vuejs are not working

Tags: vue.js

**parent component**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <custom-event @sending-start="started" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomEvent from "./element/CustomEvent.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    CustomEvent,
  },
  methods: {
    started(param) { //working
      console.log(param);
      console.log("hello");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

**child component**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>CUSTOM EVENT</h2>
    <button @click="sendData">BUTTON</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  emits: { //not working
    "sending-start"(payload) {
      if (payload.param) {
        console.log("OK emits");
        return true;
      } else {
        console.warn("no value");
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sendData() {
      this.$emit("sending-start", { param: 100 });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

So when I run this code in vuejs, the emits options in child component, It didn't work.
`started function` work in parent component. but emits options where in 13 lines of child component isn't working. I think there is no problem in this code, but I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: You are using vue2 or vue3?

Answer (score 1):

Emit handlers should always be placed only inside the parent component, thatswhy you first code block is working

If you are following vue3 syntax, then inside the child component, all you need to do is declare it

```
emits:["sending-start"]
```

whereas in vue2, that's not necessary.

Reference Link: https://learnvue.co/2020/01/a-vue-event-handling-cheatsheet-the-essentials/

Comment: Thanks for your replying.
As you said, If I declare emits which is ["sending-start"] inside child node by array, How I can make "sending-start" function like "sending-start"(payload) {}...

Comment: there is no middle function you can define, once emitted it will be handled by the `sendData` method inside the parent. If you still want to put this logic...then put it inside `sendData` method